# How to change the title from Payment Information to Payment Method in onepage checkout?

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, phtml, localisation

How to change the title PAYMENT INFORMATION to PAYMENT METHOD?

[image]

I have changed `"Payment Information","Payment Method"` in `/app/locale/en_US/Mage_Checkout.csv` but didn't work.

Comment: Any updates here?

Answer (score 1):

If you have not changed the Magento core, it should work.

Look this without updating: in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Payement.php`

```
class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
{
    $this->getCheckout()->setStepData('payment', array(
        'label' => $this->__('Payment Information'), //The translation function is well present
        'is_show' => $this->isShow()
    ));
    parent::_construct();
}
}
```

After changing it in `Mage_Checkout.csv`, clean your cach and il should work, otherwise you can always rewrite it in local

Edit:

Or you can translate it Simply with the inline translate `system->configuration->developer->select store view->Translate inline->Yes`, then go to checkout/onepage then translate it.

Comment: can you give me the file name & path to check core code?

Comment: Look my update please

Comment: It defenitly works, but please keep in mind that changing Mage_Checkout.csv is not update safe.

Comment: You could add `translate.csv`, look my update